# Union Select wrong

Tags: sql-server, select, pocketpc

I wanna do this `SELECT` for a `mobile device`

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM EMPL UNION SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM REG)
SELECT cte.NUM_EMPL, EMPL.NAME
FROM cte 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPL ON cte.NUM_EMPL = EMPL.NUM_EMPL
```

but MVS2008 says:   `Sql Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 1, Token in error = WITH]`

**Any idea??**

Comment: Since SQL server compact edition does not support CTE you might be better off using a UNION instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SQL Server Compact Edition supports Common Table Expressions. Reference [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/830d28c2-5cfd-4fcb-ae6d-b9e926322706).

As a workaround, you should be able to use the *[derived table](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150033/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/112098-1.shtml)* approach.